# How to add image to the listFragment First item only?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have implemented the fragments in android 4.0.I want to add an image to the list fragment for the first item only.

I have implemented the list fragment as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     dummyContent = (new listFragmentAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),DummyContent.ITEMS));
setListAdapter(dummyContent);   
    }
```

and `listFragmentAdapter` is as follows:

```
    public listFragmentAdapter(Context context, T[] items) {

            super(context,R.layout.list_fragment_text, items);
            this.ctx = context;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cust_view);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/segoeuil.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(tf);

            return view;
        }

}
```

Comment: check position: if(position == 0){ 'set image ' }else{ 'imageview gone' } in get view. try it

Comment: Thank you for the solution....but doesnt work in this case...

Comment: why its not working?? post full code with layout & manifest file v ll check..

Comment: The  problem in this case is that I need to find the imageview which an totally independent layout..when i try to find the imageview it throws an null pointer exception.....am trying to implement it using layout inflator now

Comment: post full code with layout & manifest file v ll check..

Comment: You need to have at least one `ImageView` in your layout. And then, add/remove your image (drawable) at `getView()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have at least one `ImageView` in your layout. And then, add/remove your image (drawable/bitmap) at `getView()` method, something like this:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.id.cust_view, null); 

// if first item
if (position == 0) {
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFirstRow);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
    imageView.setVisibility(Visible.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    // hide/remove image
    imageView.setVisibility(Visible.INVISIBLE); // or GONE, as you wish
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped me to get to proper solution.. Thank you @jelies